# Setting up PNP4nagios - Cant find Nagios Environment

Tags: ubuntu, nagios

My system is configured as follows:
Ubuntu 14.04LTS 
Nagios Core 4.0.8 
Plugins @ ver 2.0.3 
PNP 0.4.13

The latest apache, perl, rrdtool, etc.
Nagios has been working normally, just added a remote host for testing purposes.

I followed the PNP docs but I'm sure I did something wrong.

After installing PNP4nagios, the website was not reachable and I realized that pnp4nagios.conf was in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` so I executed `./configure --with-httpd-conf=/etc/apache2/conf-available` and installed it again.

The install page then showed good and everything was green. I renamed install.php into install.done.php and configured nagios to work in Synchronous Mode.

Loading http:///pnp4nagios/ I got an error telling me that perfdata dir is empty and indeed it is.

So I ran verify_pnp_config as follows:
`perl verify_pnp_config -m sync -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg -p /usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc` that gave the followinf output:

http://pastebin.com/m4revFW8

Maybe these lines are wrong?

[INFO]  host_query = 
[INFO]  service_query =

Then I set in process_perfdata.cfg LOG_LEVEL 2, who tells me in perfdata.log

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [2] Using Config File /usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/process_perfdata.cfg parameters

```
2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [2] Default Timeout: 15 secs.

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [2] Config Timeout: 15 secs.

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [2] Actual Timeout: 15 secs.

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [1] process_perfdata.pl-0.6.24 starting in SYNC Mode

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [1] Cant find Nagios Environment. Exiting ....
```

I used in commands.cfg (for host and service) the commands:

```
command_line    /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl

command_line    /usr/bin/perl /usr/local/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl -d HOSTPERFDATA
```

or

```
command_line    /usr/local/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl

command_line    /usr/local/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl -d HOSTPERFDATA
```

or

```
command_line    perl /usr/local/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl

command_line    perl /usr/local/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl -d HOSTPERFDATA
```

But I didn't make any difference.

**TL;DR**

+perfdata dir is empty.
+verify_pnp_config output is http://pastebin.com/m4revFW8 
+perfdata.log says:

```
2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [2] Using Config File /usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/process_perfdata.cfg parameters

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [2] Default Timeout: 15 secs.

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [2] Config Timeout: 15 secs.

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [2] Actual Timeout: 15 secs.

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [1] process_perfdata.pl-0.6.24 starting in SYNC Mode

2014-11-05 04:37:30 [9049] [1] Cant find Nagios Environment. Exiting ....
```

Comment: please check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16246221/1651408

Comment: @DeerHunter according to http://bugzilla.globus.org/globus/show_bug.cgi?id=6539 restarting nagios as root should solve the problem (at least temporarily) and it doesn't in my case. Thank you anyway

Comment: Why are you compiling pnp4nagios? it's packaged

Comment: @Keith, yes, that's true. I was confused about what I did with nagios and with pnp4nagios, I did all the things the same day... already edited this part. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a Nagios 4 bug, where environment data used by pnp4nagios is not provided in sync mode.

http://www.monitoring-portal.org/wbb/index.php?page=Thread&postID=210275#post210275

Switching to bulk+npcd mode, solved the problem.